# ajax call returns only last id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to develop an add to cart function via ajax, the problem is that no matter which product I add to cart, it adds the last item on the list and then increments the same product upon clicking on any other product. Here is my code:-

```
<?php         
   $i = 1;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)){  
     $op_id = $row['option_id'];

     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['option_desc'] . "</td>";    
     echo "<td> 

     <form action='' method='post' class='p_form'>
       <input type='text' name='product_id' value='$op_id'  pid='$op_id'>
       <input type='text' name='quantity' value='1'  pid='$op_id'>
       <input class='btn btn-primary add' type='submit' name='add_to_cart' value='Add to Cart' id='product' pid='$op_id'>
     </form>
   </td>";
   echo "</tr>";        
   $i++;
 }
 ?>
```

Here is jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','.p_form',function (event) {    
        event.preventDefault();

        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("pid");
         //alert(id);

              $.ajax({

                  url: 'action.php',
                  method: 'post',
                  //data: {id:id}, 
                  data:$('.p_form').serialize(), 
                  success: function(data){

                      $('#message').html(data);                          
                  }
              });

        return false;

    });

});
</script>
```

Here is `action.php`, the $product_id always returns as 4 (for example) if the last id in the last is 4

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    echo $product_id;
}
```

Comment: In Ajax you uses data:$('.p_form').serialize(), which means that it will take the one last value from the multiple class. So what you can do is create different class names or id for each form and get that value. So there will not be any duplicate problem

Comment: because you are creating same form with same name. so it will take only last form.

Comment: Use `data: $(this).serialize()`

Comment: It worked!! but can you please explain a bit, what happens in your reffered code? @Phil

Comment: @Karthick,  thanks for your comment, can you please explain how do we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do it like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.add',function (event) {//instead of form click add event on form button click    
        event.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("pid");
        //alert(id);

          $.ajax({
              url: 'action.php',
              method: 'post',
              data:element.parent('.p_form').serialize(), //serialize clicked button parent form
              success: function(data){
                  $('#message').html(data);                          
              }
          });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, would you please explain what happens in your code?

Comment: @KaleemShahid  already explained via comments. It's very simple. I have added click event to each form submit button. when any button clicked i tried to fetch it's corresponding form and serialise it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trigger click event on button click not on the form click:

This will work for you for each product.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','.add',function (event) {    
        event.preventDefault();

        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("pid");
         //alert(id);

              $.ajax({

                  url: 'action.php',
                  method: 'post',
                  data: {id:id}, //send id of product you wish to add
                  success: function(data){

                      $('#message').html(data);                          
                  }
              });

        return false;

    });

});
</script>
```

And on server side:

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
    $product_id = $_POST['id'];//get only that id posted in ajax call
    echo $product_id;
}
```